# Why can't I use two hyphens in positions 3 and 4 of a domain name?

Tags: domains

I've come across a rule, that as far as I can tell, all domain registrars share: That you cannot register a domain that has two hyphens in positions 3 and 4 of the desired domain name. Apart from that, you can put as many hyphens in your domain as you like.

Is there an explanation for this rule?

Answer (score 6):

I suspect it's something to do with [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) - the way of encoding Unicode characters into ASCII for domain names. However I don't understand the Punycode algorithm, so I can't see if allowing `xx--` would somehow break the algorithm.

Comment: +1 It gets into arcane stuff I don't follow, and will probably never have to, but I think you're in the right area here. Section 9.1.2 of [this document](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-klensin-idnabis-issues-07) specifically calls out the situation as @Cuy describes it(positions 3 & 4), though I can barely understand what it's talking about. According to a reference [here](http://www.alvestrand.no/pipermail/idna-update/2008-May/001945.html) this seems like it's a weird leftover encoding safety requirement that may or may not go away someday.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, paulmorriss and Su'. I thought it would have to do with character encoding, but I wasn't yet familiar with Punycode. I'll look into that a little. Again, thanks!

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#ToASCII_and_ToUnicode) has further details.